# AngularJS. Start stopwatch to a selected item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, stopwatch

I am trying to create my own basketball box-score making web app with angular and I have stubmled upon a problem that I can't fix.

My plan is that you first have to select a row in players table and then press a button on top to add a statistics to that column. So far everything works as I want except the time column. When I select a player and press 'Start' time will start. But when I now select another player, without stopping time, the previous player's time will stop and a other player's time will start. And so on.

I would like that the first player's time will not stop until I have selected him and pressed stop.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ReinhardVuks/bmuv5k1L/6/)

HTML

```
<div class="container" ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn" ng-click="start()">Start</button>
    <button class="btn" ng-click="stop()">Stop</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addPts()">Points</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addRbd()">Rebounds</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addAst()">Assists</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addStl()">Steals</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addBlk()">Blocks</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="addFls()">Fouls</button>

  </div>

  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <td>#</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Aeg</td>
      <td>Pts</td>
      <td>Reb</td>
      <td>Ast</td>
      <td>Stl</td>
      <td>Blk</td>
      <td>Fls</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="player in team" ng-click="selectedPlayer($index)" ng-class="{'selected': playerId == $index, 'out':player.Fouls >= 5}">
      <td>
        {{player.Nr}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{player.Name}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{player.Time | secondsToDateTime | date:'mm:ss'}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{player.Points}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{player.Rebounds}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{player.Assists}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{player.Steals}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{player.Blocks}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{player.Fouls}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout) {



  $scope.team = [{
    "Nr": 23,
    "Name": "Michael Jordan",
    "Time": 0,
    "Points": 0,
    "Rebounds": 0,
    "Assists": 0,
    "Steals": 0,
    "Blocks": 0,
    "Fouls": 0
  }, {
    "Nr": 91,
    "Name": "Dennis Rodman",
    "Time": 0,
    "Points": 0,
    "Rebounds": 0,
    "Assists": 0,
    "Steals": 0,
    "Blocks": 0,
    "Fouls": 0
  }]

  function countdown() {
    $scope.team[$scope.playerId]["Time"]++;
    $scope.timeout = $timeout(countdown, 1000);
  }

  $scope.start = function() {
    countdown();
  };

  $scope.stop = function() {
    $timeout.cancel($scope.timeout);
  };

  $scope.playerId = null;
  $scope.selectedPlayer = function(id) {
    $scope.playerId = id;

  };

  $scope.addPts = function() {
    $scope.team[$scope.playerId]["Points"] += 2;
  };
  $scope.addRbd = function() {
    $scope.team[$scope.playerId]["Rebounds"] += 1;
  };
  $scope.addAst = function() {
    $scope.team[$scope.playerId]["Assists"] += 1;
  };
  $scope.addStl = function() {
    $scope.team[$scope.playerId]["Steals"] += 1;
  };
  $scope.addBlk = function() {
    $scope.team[$scope.playerId]["Blocks"] += 1;
  };
  $scope.addFls = function() {
    if ($scope.team[$scope.playerId]["Fouls"] < 5)
      $scope.team[$scope.playerId]["Fouls"] += 1;
  };

};
myApp.filter('secondsToDateTime', [function() {
    return function(seconds) {
      return new Date(1970, 0, 1).setSeconds(seconds);
    };
  }])
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep track of all the times the way you are doing it now it is a 'global' timer whick changes the time for the selected player.

So when you click a new line the selected player id changes and the timer of that player increases

you should keep track of all the timers with

```
$scope.timers = {};
```

and change your countdown function as follows

```
function countdown(id) {
  $scope.team[id]["Time"]++;
  $scope.timers[id] = $timeout(countdown.bind(null, id), 1000);
}
```

so it creates a timeout and saves the promise returned to the timers object

and the stop function becomes

```
$scope.stop = function() {
  $timeout.cancel($scope.timers[$scope.playerId]);
};
```

check the updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bmuv5k1L/8/)

Comment: Thanks! 
But still have a little problem. The 'Stop' button doesn't work now on your fiddle. Can you help me with that also?